# Is there a way to force Blender open render window in the same monitor as the editor if using multiple monitors?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, interface

I have multiple monitors and I want to keep the other monitor for reference images and for video tutorials. When I render Image, it opens the new window in other monitor than the Blender editor is in. This is kinda frustrating when I have to move it every time out of the way, breaking my workflow.

Is there a way to change it so that it opens the render window over top of the blender editor? I still do want to keep it in separate window.

Also is there some option to have the render-window be resized to smaller window by default?

Comment: @JachymMichal I can't see setting "Temporary windows" at mentioned location. I do see setting under Render->Display Mode->Keep user interface. When it's checked, it will not show any windows apart from the editor, nor it show it's rendering, but it is if I go to "Rendering" -tab. This is not what I looked for, thanks still. I'm running Blender 2.8 on MacOS, if it has anything to do with it.